# FIXED : Firestore security rules for subscribed users

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am building a blog and I am using firestore for the database. I am trying to write security rules so that only users that are subscribed can view the content of and article but I want everyone to be able to see the articles title and photo on the homepage.

My database schema is like this:

I have a collection articles in which every document is a separate article which holds fields like the title and the photo. In every article document there is a sub collection 'protected' that holds the content of the article and I want only subscribed users to be able to get that protected info.

My rules so far are

```
 match /articles/{articleId} {
    allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'someId';

    match /articles/{articleId}/protected/{protecedId} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.subscription == true;

    }
  }
```

Howevery this stops my homepage from loading and showing any articles. Can someone help me figure out whats wrong with my rules?

UPDATED: 
My rules now look like this :

```
 match /articles/{articleId} {
    allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'someid';

     match /protected/{protectedId} {
      allow read: if true;
                allow write;
    }
  }
```

However again my homepage does not load. The only solution seems to be to add match /{document=**} to my rules. However this means all my other rules are overwritten.

FIXED:

I needed to write rules for all my collections and subcollections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't correctly declare your [hierarchical data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure?authuser=0#hierarchical_data) in your rules.

As explained in the doc linked above, "when nesting match statements, the path of the inner match statement **is always relative** to the path of the outer match statement".

Therefore, you should remove the first part of the `/articles/{articleId}/protected/{protectedId}` path, as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /articles/{articleId} {
          allow read: if true;
          allow write: ....;

          match /protected/{protecedId} {
            allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.subscription == true;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's strange. With these rules, everybody shall be able to read the articles collection (`firebase.firestore().collection('articles').get().then(...)`). I'll adapt the answer to include all the rules code. Maybe your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Fixed it when I added rules for all my collections and subscollections.